# Empty C++ if statement return a zero value?

Tags: c++, if-statement

How come when you put a empty if statement the program still produce a value (zero) for an integer variable?

It is a simple program to compare three integers and print if all or any of them are greater than 10 or not.  At line 42, there is a empty else statement with a semicolon. The program should not return z1 =0 if the user input z as 6.

```
#include <iostream> // include iostream class for input and output
#include <string> // for strings operation
#include <sstream> // for stringstream operations
using namespace std; // use defintion from std namespace

int main ()
{
   int x, y, z; // define three user-input integers
   int x1, y1, z1; // variables to hold bool values
   stringstream xyz; // variable to store whole bool value
   int XYZ; // variable to condiition print

   // prompt user for x, y and z input
   cout << "Please enter x" << "\n";
   cin >> x; 

   cout << "Please enter y" << "\n";
  cin >> y; 

  cout << "Please enter z" << "\n";
  cin >> z; 

  // generate bool values of x1, y1, z1
  if ( 10/x < 1)
     x1 = 1;
  else 
     x1 = 0;

  if ( 10/y  < 1)
     y1 = 1;
   else 
      y1 = 0;

  if ( 10/z  < 1)
     z1 = 1;
  else 
     ;


   // read into xyz and then XYZ
   xyz << x1 << y1 << z1;
   xyz >> XYZ;

  // generate 8 print statements
  if (XYZ == 111)
     ;

  if (XYZ == 000)
      cout << "x, y, z < 10" << endl;

  if (XYZ == 110)
     cout << "x, y > 10 and z < 10" << endl;

  if (XYZ == 101)
     cout << "x, z > 10 and y < 10" << endl;

  if (XYZ == 100)
  cout << "y, z < 10 and x > 10" << endl;

  if (XYZ == 011)
     cout << "y, z > 10 and x < 10" << endl;

  if (XYZ == 010)
     cout << "x, z < 10 and y > 10" << endl;

  if (XYZ == 001)
     cout << "x, y < 10 and z > 10" << endl;


} // program main ends
```

I spent hours  to research this but most discussions are about either the syntax error of a semi-colon right after the if statement or some other topics.

(Note: Line 51 is executed corrected to display nothing on the console though).

Does anyone comes cross this on Mac OSX 10.8.4? Is it to do with the default LLVM compiler?

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking. The `else ;` does nothing. Note that the `011`, `010` (all the constants that start with `0`) will be octal (base 8) instead of base 10 though, so `011` means `9`, not `11`.

Comment: `z` is just uninitialized variable if `z==6`, it can contain any value. you'd better initialize all variables when define them. Otherwise you are caught off guard by strange values.

Comment: You code has a bug, reading the value of `z1` even if it's not initialized. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Answer (score 3):

As alluded to in the comments - you're getting (un)lucky.

In C++, variables with no declared initial value, if never assigned to, can end up having *any value whatsoever* if queried. Sometimes this value is 0, sometimes this value is `0xcccccccc`, sometimes this value is whatever was last on the stack - it depends on your compiler, your program's memory layout, what you had for breakfast, etc.

If you don't assign a value to `z1`, you can't make assumptions about its behavior. If it ends up being 0, that's just coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Jerry Coffin mentioned this in his comment on your question. I tested it out and it was the issue. You've probably already solved it by now, but the literals that you provide are literally octal literals, not decimal, so the statements are not going to be true unless you get lucky.

Answer (score -4):

During the variable declaration, z1 is initialised to 0 by default. Since z1 is not being modified if z=6, so z1 will remain as 0.

Comment: While this might be true in some other languages, such as Java and C#, it's not true in C++. Granted many times the value might indeed be 0, but in general the value of an uninitialized C++ variable is just random.